# new Icon shifting design for android tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a new design in mind for android tabs. I want only images to be shown, no text. I want one image always in center and I want to rotate other images in order of swiping. So suppose, I have 3 icons for 3 tabs. Current formation is 1-2-3 with 2nd icon in center. On swiping right, it goes as 3-1-2 with 1 in center. On one more swiping right, it goes as 2-3-1. I want to show clean and smooth transition of icons in between.

Is there anything you can help me with to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout, It helped me